# Como criar JButton em formato "quadrado"?

Tags: java, swing

É possível criar `JButton` em um formato "quadrado", sem os cantos arredondados quando eles já estão no `JFrame`? Alguém tem algum exemplo?
Não uso nenhum laf específico,  e sim o default do netbeans.
Os `JButtons` não tem nada de diferente, são como na imagem (não sei se ajuda muito). Tentei tirar do `JPanel`, mas não muda em nada. Aí tem alguns eventos nos JButtons como mouse clicked, por exemplo. Os componentes já estão no JFrame, não uso nenhum código para criação, como nos exemplos citados [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379781/is-it-possible-to-force-jbutton-to-always-be-square).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
      package view;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Rodrigo
 */
public class Empresa extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Empresa
     */
    public Empresa() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel5 = 
        new JPanel(){
            public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
                Image img =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                    Principal.class.getResource("/images/ws_abstract_gray_bar.png"));
                g.drawImage(img, 0,0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
            }
        };
        jLBuscarRegistro = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTBuscarRegistro = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jBLimpar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jBusacarRegistro = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
        jPanel5.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153), null));
        jPanel5.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLBuscarRegistro.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLBuscarRegistro.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLBuscarRegistro.setText("Buscar:");
        jLBuscarRegistro.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(20, 15));
        jPanel5.add(jLBuscarRegistro, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 10, 111, 36));

        jTBuscarRegistro.setToolTipText("Insira qualquer infromação ");
        jTBuscarRegistro.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 102)));
        jPanel5.add(jTBuscarRegistro, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(130, 10, 111, 36));

        jBLimpar.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 102));
        jBLimpar.setText("Limpar");
        jBLimpar.setBorder(null);
        jBLimpar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBLimparActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel5.add(jBLimpar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 10, 111, 36));

        jBusacarRegistro.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 102));
        jBusacarRegistro.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("D:\\NetBeansProjects\\SGInf\\src\\main\\resources\\images\\help.png")); // NOI18N
        jBusacarRegistro.setBorder(null);
        jBusacarRegistro.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jBusacarRegistroActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel5.add(jBusacarRegistro, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(350, 10, 111, 36));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 492, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 472, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(117, 117, 117)
                    .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 65, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(118, 118, 118)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jBLimparActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTBuscarRegistro.setText("");
    }                                        

    private void jBusacarRegistroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insira informações");
    }                                                

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empresa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empresa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empresa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empresa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Empresa().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jBLimpar;
    private javax.swing.JButton jBusacarRegistro;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLBuscarRegistro;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTBuscarRegistro;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Teria como mostrar como está fazendo? Está usando algum *look and feel* ou é o padrão (*metal*)? Precisa disto em algum *look and feel* específico? Ter como tem, mas em alguns casos já é padrão o botão "quadrado". Mostre um [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que consigamos reproduzir.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pelo interesse, editei a pergunta para ver se torno mais claro.

Comment: Cara, continuo sem entender. O exemplo dessa pergunta no SOen gera vários botões em um painel. Tem como postar o código que gera a tela dessa imagem que incluiu? Os botões devem estar decorados (ou são imagens), então é preciso ver o código que gera para lhe ajudar.

Comment: Entendo, segue o código do form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A borda arrendondada do botão é devido ao *look and feel* que você está utilizando. Veja estre techo do seu código:

```java
for (final javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
    }
}
```

Seu programa está procurando pelo *look and feel* chamado `Nimbus` (classe `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`) e caso ache ele será usado, se não será usado o *look and feel* padrão `Metal` (classe `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel`).

Para exemplificar como alterar o comportamento dos botões no `Nimbus` irei usar uma tela que tem apenas um botão e que use ele como *look and feel*. O exemplo é este:

[image: Botão Nimbus Original]

Como já temos o por que de seus botões teres o aspecto arrendodado, temos algumas alternativas para alterá-lo conforme você precisa. São elas:

- usar o *look and feel* padrão, então pode comentar/remover este trecho do seu código:

```java
try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empresa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empresa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empresa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empresa.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Isto fará com que seja usado o aspecto padrão, que é o `Metal`, e a tela que estamos usando como exemplo ficará assim:

[image: Botão Metal]

- usar o *look and feel* do sistema. Para isto, substitua o trecho citado (o que procura pelo `Nimbus`) acima por este:

```java
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Isto fará com que seja considerado o *look and feel* do sistema em que sua aplicação está rodando, não um customizado. No meu caso, utilizando Windows 10 esta é a cara do botão:

[image: Botão Sistema]

- alterar a aparência dos botões no *look and feel* `Nimbus`, configurando as propriedades dos botões com um novo [`Painter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Painter.html). Aqui vamos usar um simples, como este:

```java
public class CustomNimbusPainter implements Painter<JButton> {

    private final Color light = Color.WHITE;
    private final Color dark = Color.GRAY;
    private GradientPaint gradPaint;

    @Override
    public void paint(final Graphics2D g, final JButton button, final int width, final int height) {
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        this.gradPaint = new GradientPaint(width / 2.0f, 0, this.light, width / 2.0f, height / 2.0f, this.dark, true);
        g.setPaint(this.gradPaint);
        g.fillRect(2, 2, width - 5, height - 5);

        final Color outline = Color.BLACK;
        g.setColor(outline);
        g.drawRect(2, 2, width - 5, height - 5);
        final Color trans = new Color(outline.getRed(), outline.getGreen(), outline.getBlue(), 100);
        g.setColor(trans);
        g.drawRect(1, 1, width - 3, height - 3);
    }

}
```

Feito isto agora temos que alterar as propriedades padrão do *look and feel* que são referente ao fundo dos botões. Vou alterar globalmente, então vamos fazer isto depois que o `Nimbus` é configurado (depois de `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());`), alterando as propriedade de botão que possuem `backgroundPainter`. O trecho ficou assim:

```java
for (final UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        final Painter<JButton> painter = new CustomNimbusPainter(Color.YELLOW, Color.RED);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Default+Focused+MouseOver].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Default+Focused+Pressed].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Default+Focused].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Default+MouseOver].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Default+Pressed].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Default].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Disabled].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Enabled].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Focused+MouseOver].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Focused+Pressed].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Focused].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[MouseOver].backgroundPainter", painter);
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button[Pressed].backgroundPainter", painter);
        break;
    }
}
```

E aquele mesmo exemplo de tela simples ficou assim:

[image: Botão Nimbus Alterado]

Para mais propriedades, verifique a documento de [componentes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#components) do `Nimbus`. Além disto, como provavelmente precisa de um botão mais estilizado, sugiro olhar [`AbstractRegionPainter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/AbstractRegionPainter.html) e também procurar por `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ButtonPainter` no seu ambiente, que é uma implementação concreta de `AbstractRegionPainter`, para que faça um [`Painter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Painter.html) da forma que precisar.

Comment: Opa, bastante informação, estou indo trabalhar agora, mas  vou ver isso assim que puder, Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Deu certo,  apenas  tive que remover o "modificador static" na classe CustomNimbusPainter  e criar um construtor vazio. Tem algum problema fazer isto? Outra coisa, para aplicar os efeitos de mouse hover, pressed posso trabalhar nesta mesma classe ? E quanto a outros componentes como JComboBox?

Comment: @Rodrigo não, pode remover o `static`, o exemplo fiz no mesmo arquivo, então o motivo de ter feito assim, já vou alterar. Pode sim usar o mesmo *painer*, só observe que você poderá ter efeitos diferentes, então talvez seja necessário manter algum estado adicional (verifique o *painter* original, ele faz algo parecido). Quanto a outros componentes, olhe o link no final que inclui, nele tem as propriedades para todos os outros componentes, incluindo `JComboBox` (iniciados com `ComboBox`)

Answer (score -1):

Acho que se voce criar Button em ves de JButton ele vem quadradinho.

Segue abaixo:

```
Button button = new Button("stack over");
button.setBounds(63, 167, 70, 22);
getContentPane().add(button);
```